# Read Permission without unlock dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, permissions, filesystems

I want to open some file from my application, file are created by the application itself and can have read or write permission.

I set read permission file with:

```
chmod 400 path
```

I want read permission file **don't show unlock dialog** when the user try to edit such files.

Is there any FS flags that can help me?

I just notice that if I try to change the owner of the file, the annoying dialog disappear, and the user can just duplicate the file in another place. This is exactly what I'm looking for but, **is this the correct way to block a file?**

Here 2 images about the involved dialogs

[image: Unlock Dialog]

[image: Allowed Dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file only have read permissions, then it must be that the file system will ask for a password if the owner (or someoneelse) tries to change the file.  Normally, one cannot change the owner of a file to some other owner ; that would be a major security hole.

Maybe what you are looking for is the stationary flag ?  This will force a user to duplicate the file to work with it, but reading it should be no problem.  You get that easily in the finder from the info window for a given file.

This is not a standard unix flag but a hfs thing.  You will have to set this using **NSFileManager** and the method

```
setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:
```

Comment: Your solution is correct and actually work. But I want to avoid any kind of dialog. In your solution a dialog appear when I open the file.

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly what you want, but you could try duplicate the file in the application and at the same time change its permission and open this.  If the file is not modified by the user, trash it, if it is, well keep it or replace the old file with it.

Comment: Don't mind. Your first solution is the correct one. The problem of the dialog for blocked file is application dependent, so it's not a big deal. Thanks for your help: accepted answer!